# Google Sheets API spreadsheets.values.get returning wrong date value

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm accessing Google spreadsheet data from node.js as follows:

```js
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId,
        range
    });

    const rows = res.data.values;
```

For reference, I'm using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).

There is one cell with the value `9/24/2019`. It's formatted as a date and is definitely not stored as a string. However, the value for that cell from the API call is `"9/24/3019"`.

There are other cells with the same value that are correct. I checked the document version history, and this cell has never had any other value.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the values of dateTimeRenderOption and valueRenderOption in the request parameters of spreadsheets.values.get?

Comment: That's a good idea, but it didn't change the date value.

Comment: Could you include a sample spreadsheet? I tried to replicate the data and send a request using [spreadsheets.values.get tester](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) 
 and I was able to get the correct date value.

Comment: In this case, I thought that to directly see your issue might lead to the solution and understanding your issue. How about this? So, in order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the value for replicating your issue?

Comment: The spreadsheet with the problem is proprietary data and I can't share it. I tried copy/pasting the cells into a new document, but the problem does not persist in the new spreadsheet. Perhaps I will file a bug report.